# Create a Bar Graph from 5 .csv files

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I need to create a Bar Graph in javascript or php from 5 .csv files. I need to show just total number of rows of each file

For example, if all files have total numbers of rows 3,4,5,6,7 respectively then I want to show these on vertical or horizontal bars.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.getJSON("lastfile.php", function(result) {

            var data = {
                labels : result[0],
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: "file",
                        fillColor: "rgba(25,150,35,0.5)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(25,150,35,0.8)",
                        highlightFill: "rgba(25,150,35,0.75)",
                        highlightStroke: "rgba(25,150,35,1)",
                        data : result[1]
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var graph = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, {
                    barValueSpacing : 15,
                    legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
            });

            document.getElementById("bar-chart-legend").innerHTML = graph.generateLegend();
        });

    });
```

Comment: missing what is the problem and the library of chart you are using (chart js I believe)

Comment: Yes, I am using chart.js.

Comment: Making sure this gets picked up by the proper group (chartjs). Not much more to edit, a sample of the data would help.

Comment: Move title into body and update title to be more concise